# php file showing syntax error when using null values

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am getting the following error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.$E_phone_No."'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in E:\Xamp\htdocs\CreateEmployee.php on line 28

What is the error, I am facing a problem and I can't find the error.

```
<?php
                   $conn=oci_connect("system","123","localhost/orcl");
    ob_start();
    $current_file=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    $massage= "";
    if(isset($_POST['E_First_Name'])&&
    isset($_POST['E_Last_Name'])&&isset($_POST['E_Gender'])&&
    isset($_POST['E_address'])&&isset($_POST['E_phone_No'])&&
    isset($_POST['E_category'])&&isset($_POST['EMP_salary'])&&
    isset($_POST['work_hour'])&&isset($_POST['Date_Of_Join'])                      )
    {

        $E_First_Name= $_POST['E_First_Name'];
        $E_Last_Name = $_POST['E_Last_Name'];
        $E_Gender = $_POST['E_Gender'];
        $E_address = $_POST['E_address'];
        $E_phone_No = $_POST['E_phone_No'];
        $E_category = $_POST['E_category'];
        $EMP_salary = $_POST['EMP_salary'];
                                       $work_hour =$_POST['work_hour'];
                                       $Date_Of_Join=$_POST['Date_Of_Join'];

        if(!empty($E_First_Name)&&!empty($E_Last_Name)&&
        !empty($E_Gender)&&!empty($E_address)&&!empty($E_phone_No)&&
        !empty($E_category)&&!empty($EMP_salary)&&!empty( $work_hour)&&!empty($Date_Of_Join))
        {

                 $sql = "insert into Employee (E_First_Name,E_Last_Name,user_name,password,E_Gender,E_address,E_phone_No,E_category,EMP_salary,work_hour,Date_Of_Join) values('".$E_First_Name."','".$E_Last_Name."',NULL,NULL,'".$E_Gender."','".$E_address."',"'.$E_phone_No."','".$E_category .'",'".$EMP_salary.'",'".  $work_hour.'","'.$Date_Of_Join.'")";

                $stid = oci_parse($conn,$sql);
                $r = @oci_execute($stid);
                if($r)
                {
                    echo ' data is inserted...<br>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'data was not inserted...<br>';
                }

        }
        else
        {
            $massage = "please fill up all the form correctly<br>";
        }
    }

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Create FoodItem Table</title>
<style>
body
{
background:orange;
}
</style>
<head>
<body>
fill all the forms for inserting data:<br><br>
<?php echo $massage;?>
<hr color="green">
<form action="<?php echo $current_file;?>" method="POST">

    E_First_Name:<br> <input type="text" name ="E_First_Name" ><br><br>
    E_Last_Name:<br> <input type="text" name="E_Last_Name" ><br><br>
    E_Gender:<br> <input type="text" name="E_Gender" ><br><br>
    E_address:<br> <input type="text" name ="E_address"><br><br>
    E_phone_No:<br> <input type= "text" name="E_phone_No" ><br><br>
    E_category:<br><input type="text" name="E_category"><br><br>
    EMP_salary:<br><input type="text" name="EMP_salary" ><br><br>
    work_hour:<br><input type="text"name="work_hour"><br><br>
                  Date_Of_Join:<br><input type="text"name="Date_Of_Join"><br><br>
    <input type ="submit" value="Create employee "><br><br>
    <a href="EmployeeTableshow.php">Show Employee Table</a>

</form>
</body>
```

Comment: If you look at your code highlighting in your question, you should be able to see the transposed `"'` and `'"`. Note that simple variables like `$var` automatically expand in double quoted strings, so interpolating string concatenation is not necessary.

Comment: $E_address."',"'.$E_phone_No."'

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the quotes mismatches for the four following variables in your VALUES:

`$E_phone_No` `$E_category` `$work_hour` `$Date_Of_Join`

---

```
"'.$E_phone_No."','".$E_category .'"
```

To be changed to:

```
'".$E_phone_No."','".$E_category ."'
```

***as well as:***

```
'".  $work_hour.'","'.$Date_Of_Join.'"
```

To be changed to:

```
'".  $work_hour."','".$Date_Of_Join."'
```

VALUES rewrite:

```
('".$E_First_Name."','".$E_Last_Name."',NULL,NULL,'".$E_Gender."','".$E_address."','".$E_phone_No."','".$E_category ."','".$EMP_salary."','".$work_hour."','".$Date_Of_Join."')
```

You may also want to add spacing between `"text"` and `"name=...` (*for clarity*):

```
<input type="text"name="Date_Of_Join">
```

to:

```
<input type="text" name="Date_Of_Join">
```

---

It has already been addressed in a comment, that your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax highlighter shows your error. You have a quotes issue:

```
$EMP_salary.'",'".  $work_hour.'","'.$Date_Of_Join.'")";
             ^^^^^^
               HERE
```

Change it to:

```
$EMP_salary.'","'.  $work_hour.'","'.$Date_Of_Join.'")";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrong concatenation of your query and your variables the correct way to insert string in the query is

```
'".$variable."'
```

Somewhere you place the closing single quote before the double while you should do the opposite. So change this part

```
NULL,'".$E_Gender."','".$E_address."','".$E_phone_No."','".$E_category ."','".$EMP_salary."','".  $work_hour."','".$Date_Of_Join."')";
```